# Unable to view image using image_view in ROS Indigo with rosberrypi_cam

Tags: ros, calibration, camera-calibration, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have succesfully installed the rosberrypi_cam package following this [page](https://github.com/japonophile/rosberrypi_cam). After that when I execute the command

```
rosrun rosberrypi_cam rosberrypi_cam_node
```

the red light on camera becomes on, showing a message,

```
[ INFO] [1506259295.746458853]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1506259295.747325311]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/pi/.ros/camera_info//rosberrypi_cam.yaml
[ INFO] [1506259295.747978384]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/pi/.ros/camera_info//rosberrypi_cam.yaml]
[ WARN] [1506259295.748239009]: Camera calibration file /home/pi/.ros/camera_info//rosberrypi_cam.yaml not found.
```

Now when I try to view an image using,

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/rosberrypi_cam/image_raw
```

I get the following message,

```
 [ INFO] [1506259415.296537089]: Using transport "raw"
(image_raw:1697): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
Aborted
```

Even while trying to calibrate the camera using cameraclibrator.py I am unable to calibrate it since the calibration window is opening as half black with all buttons disabled and without checkerboard. I am unable to understand the problem. Plesae help...
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273258/unable-to-view-image-using-image_view-in-ros-indigo-with-rosberrypi_cam/) by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on 2018-10-14**:
Hey, did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just check if in your source code, you have put
cv::startWindowThread();
before
cv::waitKey(10);

If yes, just remove the startWindowThread function. It worked for me,

---

Originally posted by [Smit585](https://answers.ros.org/users/37362/smit585/) with karma: 36 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on 2018-10-14**:
Hey, I am in a similar situation. What source code are you talking about, the source code for image_view node?

**Comment by [matkok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30173/matkok/) on 2019-03-15**:
I worked for me by downloading image_view package in my workspace, and commenting out line 178. - //cv::startWindowThread();

**Comment by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on 2019-06-08**:
This works, but at this date 2019/Jun/09, it has not been fixed in the image_view package. In the meanwhile I use rqt_image_view. This is an error in the image view package I think because if I open a WIndows using OpenCV functions it does not crash.